# WPF - Create a UI object from a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

This is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178387/get-the-ui-object-from-a-data-object) I asked earlier.  I am hoping to be clearer and get a different answser.

I have a Data Object (called MockUI).  It has a data template (in app.xaml) like this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MockWI}">
    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

In my code I want **create** a UI object that what the data template is.  So I have myMockWI and I want to find out what template that would use and get the object it creates (in this case a button with the content set to myMockWI).

I have tried to just make a button:

```
Button myButton = new Button {Content = myMockWI}
```

but as you can probably guess, that creates the button then puts another button inside that button (because the data template is applied).  How can I get one button only?

Comment: Can you spend some more time on your post.. it's a bit confusing. What is the use-case for this? Is MockWI a typo of MockUI ? Are you trying to programatically retrieve the view (created from a datatemplate) of a specific instance ?

Comment: @Gishu: thanks for the hint on needing a better post.  I think I figured this one out on my own or I would absolutely put in better/more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that I just needed to go up the UI tree a bit.

If I make a new ContentControl then it has no Look to it and takes on whatever the datatemplate is.

So my code changes from above to this:

```
ContentControl myControl = new ContentControl {Content = myMockWI};
```

Comment: You are correct in doing so. Anything that derives from ContentControl may also use the DataTemplate with DataType set to host the data object, eg. ContentPresenter, ListBox, ListView, etc.